# Why can't I duplicate selected items in for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Like I have a list: `letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']`
and I want to insert `'c'` at the first of the list:

```
for letter in letters:
    if letter == 'c':
        letters.insert(0, letter)
```

When I hit enter there's nothing happen and I have to force quit my terminal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why your code loops forever is you keep inserting an element at the start so all the elements get shifted so you continuously find `"c"` and hit an infinite loop, you can see below that when you insert all the elements shift over one:

```
 ["a","b","c"] # 3rd iteration   at "c" c == c insert new c 
   0,  1 , 2

 ["c","a","b","c"] # 4th at "c" again c == c insert new c
   0,  1, 2 , 3

 ["c","c","a","b","c"] # 5th at "c" again! c == c insert new c ....
  0,   1,  2 , 3,  4
```

A quicker and safe way  would be to count the occurrences and then create a new list:

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
cn = letters.count("c")
letters = ["c"] * letters.count("c") + letters

print(letters)
```

Every time you do an insert you have to move all the elements in the list so if you have a lot of matches you are going to be doing a lot of moving.

Answer (score 7):

You should never mutate lists, dictionaries or other such containers while iterating over them. One way around it is to make a copy for iteration:

```
for letter in letters[:]:
    if letter == 'c':
        letters.insert(0, letter)
```

Comment: Agree, never mutate an iterable while iterating over it. This is good advice not only for Python.

Comment: or if you mutate it, end the loop immediately

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun try this :)

```
import time
letter = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for letter in letters:
    if letter == 'c':
        letters.insert(0, letter)
        print(letters)
        time.sleep(1)
```